# A way to enforce use of interface in C++

Tags: c++, interface

In C++, let's say I have a class **`Derived`** that implements an interface class **`BaseInterface`**, where **`BaseInterface`** has only pure virtual functions and a virtual destructor:

```
class BaseInterface
{
  public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    ~BaseInterface(){}
};

class Derived : public BaseInterface
{
  public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived(){}

  protected:
    virtual void doSomething();

  private:
    int x;
};
```

No classes outside the `Derived` class hierarchy should call `Derived::doSomething()` directly, i.e., it should only be accessed polymorphically through the `BaseInterface` class.  To enforce this rule, I have made `Derived::doSomething()` protected.  This works well, but I'm looking for opinions pro/con regarding this approach.

Thanks!

Ken

Comment: If your method is not part of public interface (not for usage outside of class), why make it `public`?

Comment: @Nekuromento The problem is that C++ lets you do things like class Foo: public Derived { public: virtual void doSomething(); } foo; foo.Derived::doSomething(); which would bypass Foo's definition.

Comment: Remember to make your BaseInterface destructor virtual too

Comment: Regarding the foo.Derived::doSomething() example, I just tried that, and I got a compile error saying that Derived::doSomething() is protected, which is what I expected.

Comment: Regarding the first comment, I want the method to be part of the public interface.  I just don't want the implementation of that interface to be public.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for the non-virtual interface (NVI) pattern: a `public` non-virtual interface that calls a protected or private `virtual` implementation:

```
class BaseInterface
{
  public:
    virtual ~BaseInterface(){}
    void doSomething() { doSomethingImpl(); }

protected:
    virtual void doSomethingImpl() = 0;
};

class Derived : public BaseInterface
{
  public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived(){}

  protected:
    virtual void doSomethingImpl();

  private:
    int x;
};
```

Comment: Nice usage of the abstract method pattern!

Comment: I like this approach better than my original code snippet, because it shows the intent better and seals up the holes pointed out by others in this thread.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4):

If it is part of the interface, why would you not want users to call it? Note that as it is, they can call it: `static_cast<BaseInterface&>(o).doSomething()` is just an awkward way of saying `o.doSomething()`. What is the point of *using the interface*... if the object fulfills the interface, then you should be able to use it, or am I missing something?

Since you are not actually blocking anyone from calling the methods, I don't see a point in making the code more complex (both the class and users of the class) for no particular reason. Note that this is completely different from the Non-Virtual Interface in that in this idiom virtual functions are not accessible publicly (at any level) while in your case, the intention is allowing access, and making it cumbersome.

Comment: +1. And also I think changing the visibility of methods in derived classes is not such a good style, as it can lead to various confusions.

Comment: I do want users to call the function.  I just don't want them to be coupled to the implementation.  It's basically applying the open-closed principle.  I do see, however, how the NVI pattern makes this intent clearer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is also mentioned in standard ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) 11.6.1 and believe you are correct. Other than the fact, the member function isn't pure virtual in the given example. It should hold for pure virtual functions too, AFAIK.

> The access rules (clause 11) for a virtual function are determined by its declaration and are not affected by the rules for a function that later overrides it.

```
[Example:

   class B 
   { 
     public:
     virtual int f();
   };

   class D : public B 
   { 
     private:
     int f();
   };

   void f() 
   {
     D d; 
     B* pb = &d; 
     D* pd = &d;

     pb->f(); // OK: B::f() is public, 
              // D::f() is invoked

     pd->f(); // error: D::f() is private
   }

—end example]
```

> Access is checked at the call point using the type of the expression used to denote the
>   object for which the member function is called (B* in the example above). The access of the member function in the class in which it was defined (D in the example above) is in general not known.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the rest of your code.  Only accept a BaseInterface* as an argument to any methods that require the doSomething() call.  The client programmer is forced to derive from the interface to make his code compile.

Comment: Applying the open-closed principle, the implementation instance would be created elsewhere, perhaps by a factory, and passed to clients polymorphically through the interface--probably via a functio parameter.  So the idea is that the clients would never now what the actual implementation is at compile time.  This also makes the code more easily unit testable.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense to me. Regardless of which pointer you call `doSomething()`, you would still wind up with the method defined in most derived class. Consider the following scenario:

```
class BaseInterface
{
  public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    ~BaseInterface(){}
};

class Derived : public BaseInterface
{
  public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived(){}

      virtual void doSomething(){}

  private:
    int x;
};

class SecondDerived : public Derived
{
  public:
    SecondDerived() {}
    ~SecondDerived(){}

  private:
    int x;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SecondDerived derived;
    derived.doSomething(); //Derived::doSomething is called

    BaseInterface* pInt = &derived;
    pInt->doSomething(); //Derived::doSomething is called

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea would be to make Derived::doSomething protected, so if any clients outside the hierarchy tried to call it, they would get a compile error.  This would let the compiler enforce the rule that  the function should only be used through the abstract interface, since that is the only place the function is public.  So in the end, it has the compiler forcing clients to remain decoupled from the implementation.